# Factorization of a polynomial into irreducible factors

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

$f(x)$ = $x^5$+$2x^2$+$2x$+$2$ $ \in Z_3[x]$

How do i factorize it into irreducible factors ?

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: $f(0), f(1), f(2)$ are not $0$ mod 3, so if this factors it must have a quadratic factor and a cubic factor. Without loss of generality, you can assume the quadratic factor is monic. Now run through the finite list of quadratic irreducibles in $Z_3[x]$ and do some long division to see which of these is possibly a factor.

Comment: @user44441 Thank you, i got it !

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $i=\sqrt{-1}$ in an extension field of $\Bbb{Z}_3$, then
$$
f(i)=i^5+2(i^2+1)+2i=i+0+2i=3i=0.
$$

Comment: Alternatively
$$f(x)=x^5-x^2-x-1=x(x^4-1)-(x^2+1).$$